# Error in magento admin print page

Tags: php, magento

I developed on e commerce website in magento

When i click print button in magento invoice admin page the error is occur

```
    Table offset (1445424) not within expected range

Trace:
#0 /var/www/ecommerce/lib/Zend/Pdf/Font.php(615): Zend_Pdf_Font::_extractTrueTypeFont(Object(Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File), 0)
#1 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(807): Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/var/www/ecommerce/l...')
#2 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(113): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->_setFontBold(Object(Zend_Pdf_Style), 10)
#3 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(119): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Array)
#4 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction()
#5 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction()
#6 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#7 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /var/www/ecommerce/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /var/www/ecommerce/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/ecommerce/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

how to fix this issue?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

**It's Working for me !!**

> This bug appears to be happening for me on Magento installs on PHP 5.4 and above.

```
Change
```

abstract public function __construct();

```
to
```

abstract public function __construct($filePath);

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, and for me the fix was to re-upload all the fonts inside lib/ which somehow got corrupted.